# Html + Jquery +for accordion

Tags: jquery, html

I am implementing "ACCORDION" in my application using HTML and Jquery. In that i have accordion inside an accordion.

My sample code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="filtersContainer" class="span12 controlPanel" style="border-radius: 6px;margin-top: 3px;">
        <div class="panel-helpers">
            <ul class="unstyled">
                <li class="helper-collapse"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form-filters-container" onclick="collapse_fun()" id="idFilters"><i class="icon-minus-sign no-underline" ></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h4 style="line-height: 40px;">Filters</h4>

        <div id="form-filters-container" class="collapse in">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="panel-helpers">
                            <ul class="unstyled">
                                <li class="helper-collapse"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demographics" onclick="collapse_demo()" id="idDemographics"><i class="icon-minus-sign no-underline"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <legend><a>Demographics</a></legend>

                        <div id="demographics" class="queryOptionGroup collapse in">
                            <table id="tableId" style="margin-left:10px;"></table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

My onclick method:

```
function collapse_fun(){
    console.log("collapse_fun");
    $('.collapse').on('hide', function () {console.log("hide ");
        //$(this).siblings(".panel-helpers").find(".helper-collapse").find("a").html("<i class='icon-plus-sign no-underline'></i>");
       document.getElementById('idFilters').innerHTML = "<i class='icon-plus-sign no-underline'></i>";
    })
    $('.collapse').on('show', function () {console.log("show ");
        //$(this).siblings(".panel-helpers").find(".helper-collapse").find("a").html("<i class='icon-minus-sign no-underline'></i>");
       document.getElementById('idFilters').innerHTML = "<i class='icon-minus-sign no-underline'></i>";
    })
}
// collapse
function collapse_demo(){
    console.log("collapse_demo");
    $('.collapse').on('hide', function () {console.log("hide 1");
        //$(this).siblings(".panel-helpers").find(".helper-collapse").find("a").html("<i class='icon-plus-sign no-underline'></i>");
       document.getElementById('idDemographics').innerHTML = "<i class='icon-plus-sign no-underline'></i>";
    })
    $('.collapse').on('show', function () {console.log("show 1");
    //$(this).siblings(".panel-helpers").find(".helper-collapse").find("a").html("<i class='icon-minus-sign no-underline'></i>");
       document.getElementById('idDemographics').innerHTML = "<i class='icon-minus-sign no-underline'></i>";
    })
}
```

But whenever i click icon for 1st accordion ,second accordion icon is also changing.. How can i solve this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: jQuery UI has a nice Accordion...

Comment: Hey refer this http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/ you can get an idea of nested accordions

Answer (score 0):

You have given the inner accordion the same `class` names as the outer accordion, and because of the way you wrote your javascript it applies the effect to all elements of that class name.

You need to rewrite your javascript to apply the effect only on the current accordion clicked on (`this`) and not every element with that `class` name. SAM has a good example in the comments above.